# NanoHTTPD を使って、コールバックの結果を返却したい

Tags: android, java

NanoHTTPDを使っています。

`public Response serve(IHTTPSession session)`の中で、
コールバックメソッドを実行して、その結果が帰ってきたら、値を返却したいのですが、どうすれば出来るでしょうか？

```
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
  命令実行(); // 完了後、コールバック関数が呼ばれる
  return;    //←　ここでレスポンスを返却したくないのですが、返却してしまいます。
}

コールバック関数() {
  // ここでレスポンスを返却したいのですが、返却できません。
}
```

方法をご存じの方お教えください。

Comment: おっしゃられている「コールバック関数」というのは「非同期で実行されるコールバック関数」の意でよろしいでしょうか。(であればsleep等を使用してコールバック関数完了まで同期待ちが良いかと思います。)

Comment: そうです。よろしければ実装例を教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状serve()はreturnでresponseを返すものしか用意されていないので、
同期制御を行うしかないと思います。

実装イメージとしては以下です。

```
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
  命令実行(); // 非同期にてコールバック関数が呼ばれる
  synchronized (syncToken)
  {
      try {
          syncToken.wait(); //notifyされるまでwaitする
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  result = hoge.getXXXXX(); //コールバック関数から結果受け取り
  return new Response(result);
}

コールバック関数() {

  ～処理～

  hoge.setXXXX(result); //serveへ結果渡し
  synchronized(syncToken){
     syncToken.notify(); //wait解除
  }
}
```

事前にsyncTokenは共有しておく必要があります。

Comment: 勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。